# SqlParameterCollection.Add is obsolete and deprecated

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting squiggly lines underneath the following code

```
sda2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@from", from);
sda2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@to", to);
```

A mouseover states that `SqlParameterCollection` is obsolete
and Add(String ..) part of the above is deprecated
I could not find anything on the internet that clarifies this
issue. However, it does work and there are no errors

Comment: Documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx  - the recommended replacement is `AddWithValue()`

Comment: It's similar, but I'd argue it may *not* be a duplicate, because the other is MySql-specific and this is (I believe) SQL Server-specific. The two happen to use similar syntax, but they're separate libraries.

Answer (score 1):

`AddWithValue` is the method that 'replaced' it:

> AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
>   a String and an Object. The overload of Add that takes a string and an
>   object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add overload that takes a String and a
>   SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string
>   could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
>   corresponding SqlDbType value. Use AddWithValue whenever you want to
>   add a parameter by specifying its name and value.

[MSDN: SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)