# How to declare param in c# function to get both inputoutput with oracle db?

Tags: c#, oracle, model-view-controller

I am newly with c# MVC that passing param value to oracle PROCEDURE. It is possible to declare param set both input and output from db? 
that currently my code:

```
 public string get_data(out string send_get)

 cmd.Parameters.Add("send_get", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

Am i right with this param declaration? 
If anyone have experience with it please kindly help me please. thanks in advance

Comment: You would be better off with creation of separate `OracleParameter` object and then  using the object to set various properties, before adding that to the Parameter Collection

Answer (score 0):

If you try the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("send_get", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

you will get a warning **"SqlParameterCollection.Add is obsolete and deprecated"**. You can use [AddWithValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue_System_String_System_Object_).

Or you can use this as well:

```
OracleParameter par = new OracleParameter("@param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 250);
par.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
par.Value = "Foo";
cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
```

For deprecated method Add refer to this SO:

[SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: Thanks but my db not SqlDbType it oracle can i replace SqlDbType  to OracleDbType?

Comment: @chhenghong you shall certainly use `OracleDbType`, since `SqlDbType` is meant for the Sql Server

Comment: edited the answer. If you are ok, please mark it as answer. It will help others also.

Comment: @Gauravsa your answer still contain parts of `SqlParameter`, remove that and verify the behavior for `OracleParameter`

Comment: @Gauravsa also why would the `SqlParameterCollection.Add`method deprecate, Could you post the Link with details

Comment: Just copied from visual studio ide. It compiles.

Comment: See here. IDE shows squiggly lines and indicates it as deprecated. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731035/sqlparametercollection-add-is-obsolete-and-deprecated