# Adding Multiple txtbox value to columns datatable row by row in single button? C# Sql

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

I have `5 columns` and more than `10 records` to save.

What I tried is to insert more than 10 rows with a single button `click.event`

I'm using parameters and repeats like this to create records from more than 10 texboxes / labels and insert the values into dbo.Transaksi in a single run.

```
string FakturID = "BSCB";
private void btnsave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 lblidKode.Text = "";
            SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select isnull(max(cast(idKode as int)),0)+1 from Laporan", con);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            sda2.Fill(dt2);
            lblidKode.Text = dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            lblidstruk.Text = FakturID + this.lblidKode.Text;

            con.Close();
//INSERT TRANSAKSI
            //BasoSU
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn1.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", txtBasoSpecialUrat.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            //BasoC
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn2.Text);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", txtBasoC.Text);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            //BasoMie
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
            cmd4.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
            cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn3.Text);
            cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", txtBasoM.Text);
            cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            //Baso Bihun
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
            cmd5.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
            cmd5.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn4.Text);
            cmd5.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", txtBasoB.Text);
            cmd5.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
            cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();




            MessageBox.Show("Berhasil Tersimpan Dalam Laporan!");
            con.Close();
//Refresh
            this.Hide();
            Meja1 lm = new Meja1();
            lm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Is there a better way to achieve such a goal?

Comment: Please avoid using the overload of `.Add` function, instead use `.AddWithValue`

Comment: what's the different? @Simo

Comment: That's [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731035/sqlparametercollection-add-is-obsolete-and-deprecated) you should use `.AddWithValue`

Answer (score 1):

One of the option will be **create a Stored procedure which will accept either XML or user defined Datatype** as input parameter.

By using select from XML or datatype into actual table you will be able to insert record in the database without using any loop.

Comment: @SagarShrike is it possible to loop the same parameters changing their value instead of coding them x times?

Comment: @Simo.. If you want to go for that approach then I would suggest to use stringBuilder class and create single string variable having semicolon separated multiple insert statements. For Building this string you can use loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xml value as ntext parameter of "Store Procedure " for example :

```
<data><t>text1</t><t>text2</t></data>
```

used as ntext parameter in store procedure.

you could use sql functions that reads xml and convert each tag  as new row.